# VBA Removing pivot subtotals from several sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using below macro to remove subtotals on the active sheet. However, I was thinking that instead of using it 5 times (and having to select the sheet each time before using the macro) it could be adjusted to either Loop (probably not as there's 12 sheets with pivot tables and I'm only interested in 5) or use the Case to define the sheets with pivot tables I need modified.

Problem is I'm still quite new to VBA and couldn't manage to make it work so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Base Code:

```
Sub NoSubtotals()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
            pf.Subtotals(1) = True
            pf.Subtotals(1) = False
        Next pf
    Next pt
End Sub
```

Sheets with Pivot Tables I want to remove subtotals from:

- Header
- Item_Breakdown
- Settl_List
- MatDef
- All_Records

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the worksheets you want to use:

```
Sub NoSubtotals()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("Header", _
                                    "Item_Breakdown", _
                                    "Settl_List", _
                                    "MatDef", _
                                    "All_Records"))

        On Error Resume Next
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
                pf.Subtotals(1) = True
                pf.Subtotals(1) = False
            Next pf
        Next pt
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very easy. Didn't think of defining the array with the required sheets. Have a nice day!